# JavaScript removeEventlistener callback with argument

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Currently I'm trying to do like this:

```
el.addEventListener('scroll', callFunc);

el.removeEventListener('scroll', callFunc);
```

But with callback function which has parameters

```
el.addEventListener('scroll', () => callFunc(pr1, pr2));

el.removeEventListener('scroll', () => callFunc(pr1, pr2));
```

Is it possible to remove eventListener callback funcion with parameters?

Comment: Extract the listener _i.e.  the arrow function as variable_ and do what you do

Answer (score 2):

1. Create function with bounded arguments:

```
const func = callFunc.bind(null, pr1, pr2);
```

2. Pass created function to `addEventListener` and `removeEventListener`.

Comment: Perhaps binding to `el` instead of `null` would be a better idea for the sake of `this` in the callback.